# Why can't display a DateTime object

Tags: php

```
$date = new DateTime(2011-10-05);
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Running the above code, the page is displayed nothing. Just wondering is there anything wrong on the code and I used the **PHP5 (Version 5.3.0)**.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

**--Update---
After adding quotes, still nothing is displayed.**

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-10-05");
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: Is `display_errors` on in php.ini? Are you using output buffering?

Answer (score 2):

`new DateTime(2011-10-05)` is equal to `new DateTime(1996)` and thus makes no sense. You probably meant `new DateTime('2011-10-05')`

Answer (score 1):

Use quotes around the date when you create the object:

```
$date = new DateTime("2011-10-05");
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, your code works fine but you did not put the date in quotes, and thus PHP considers it as the formula

```
2011 - 10 - 05
```

Which gives 1996. You'll want to give it a string instead. [Either way, it works fine](http://codepad.viper-7.com/lrjooQ).

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to make the argument you're passing to the `DateTime` constructor a string. This fixes it:

```
$date = new DateTime('2011-10-05');
```

Answer (score 1):

Quotes weren't my fix for the "displayed nothing" problem, either (PHP 5.3.10 on Win 7 Enterprise, 64-bit).  @gnud's suggestion pointed me to my problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message
>   'DateTime::__construct(): It is not safe to rely on the
>   system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the
>   date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set()
>   function.

New code:

```
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago');
$dateNow = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
echo $dateNow->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Gives the expected result:

```
2012-09-04 17:12:28
```